# find count of childrens of last div with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**My Html Code**

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="buyerblock">
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername1" id="buyername1" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 5px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyeremail1" id="buyeremail1" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
  <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername2" id="buyername2" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 9px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text"><input class="form-control" name="buyeremail2" id="buyeremail2" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button></div></div>
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
  <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername3" id="buyername3" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 9px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyeremail3" id="buyeremail3" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="addbuyerbtn" class="btn btn-primary addbutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">+</button>
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**My JS code**

```
var check = $("div.buyerdiv").last().$(".form-group").children().length;
alert(check);
```

I want to get the count of child elements of form-group class under last buyerdiv class. How can i achieve it ?
Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var check = $("div.buyerdiv").last().find(".form-group").children().length;
    alert(check);
```

Comment: I'd use `.children('.form-group')` instead of `find`, especially if there could be a large number of descendants or if `form-group` elements can be nested. It will look only at the children of the last `buyerdiv` element rather than all descending elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$` use `find()`

```js
var check = $("div.buyerdiv").last().find(".form-group").children().length;
console.log(check);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6" id="buyerblock">
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername1" id="buyername1" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 5px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyeremail1" id="buyeremail1" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
  <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername2" id="buyername2" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 9px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text"><input class="form-control" name="buyeremail2" id="buyeremail2" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button></div></div>
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
  <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername3" id="buyername3" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 9px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyeremail3" id="buyeremail3" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="addbuyerbtn" class="btn btn-primary addbutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">+</button>
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on fiddle with `find()`.

```js
var count = $('#buyerblock').find('.form-group').size();
alert(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6" id="buyerblock">
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername1" id="buyername1" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 5px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyeremail1" id="buyeremail1" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
  <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername2" id="buyername2" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 9px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text"><input class="form-control" name="buyeremail2" id="buyeremail2" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button></div></div>
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
  <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername3" id="buyername3" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 9px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyeremail3" id="buyeremail3" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="addbuyerbtn" class="btn btn-primary addbutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">+</button>
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code, just use following line

```
$("div.buyerdiv").last().find(".form-group").children().length;
```

```js
var check = $("div.buyerdiv").last().find(".form-group").children().length;
alert(check);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6" id="buyerblock">
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername1" id="buyername1" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 5px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyeremail1" id="buyeremail1" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
  <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername2" id="buyername2" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 9px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text"><input class="form-control" name="buyeremail2" id="buyeremail2" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button></div></div>
 <div class="form-inline buyerdiv">
  <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyername3" id="buyername3" style="margin-bottom: 3px;margin-right : 9px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Name" type="text">
        <input class="form-control" name="buyeremail3" id="buyeremail3" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="" placeholder="Enter Buyer Email" type="email">
        <button type="button" id="addbuyerbtn" class="btn btn-primary addbutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">+</button>
        <button type="button" id="removebuyerbtn" class="btn btn-danger removebutton" style="margin-left: 19px;">-</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have small mistake.

just use find() Instead of $

var check = $("div.buyerdiv").last().find(".form-group").children().length;
alert(check);